# Frame Busting buster not completely working for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, framebusting

I've been working on a Frame busting buster (what's in a name, hehe), which kept my users on my page and open a new window with the target URL. I'm using a Lightbox script to display iframes, this is what I'm doing:

1) Added an event for all .lightbox clicks, f.e:

```
$('.lightbox').live("click", function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#redirectURL').val($(this).attr('href')); 
  $(this).lightbox(); 
}
```

2) Added a frame busting buster:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
      if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
        prevent_bust -= 2  
        window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com'  
      }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

3) Modified the frame busting buster code to fit my needs, which are:

- detect if an iframe wants to change the window.top.location
- if so, prevent this from happening using the 204 server respond
- open a new page: `window.open( $('#redirectURL', '_blank' );`
- close lightbox: `$('.jquery-lightbox-button-close').click();`

So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
var prevent_bust = 0  
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
setInterval(function() {  
  if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
    prevent_bust -= 2;
    redirectURL = $('#redirectURL').val();
    if(redirectURL != "") {
        window.top.location = 'http://www.****.com/ajax/nocontent.php';
        window.open(redirectURL, "_blank");
        $('.jquery-lightbox-button-close').click();
        $('#redirectURL').val('');
    } else {
        window.top.location = 'http://www.****.com/ajax/nocontent.php';
    }
  }  
}, 1);
```

// EDIT: `Before I forget, 'nocontent.php' is a file that returns a 204 header`

For Firefox it acts as I programmed it, if there's a change detected in the window.top.location it opens a new frame/page and prevents the iframe from reloading the top location and to round it up, it closes the jQuery lightbox.

Safari/Chrome act similar, they open a new browser screen (`not sure if theres an option to say target="_newtab" or something?`). Only bad thing is they do not really display a message of the popup is blocked, but I can work around that by displaying a popup balloon on my website with a link to the page.

Internet Explorer is, what a shocker, the only black sheep left.. IE does not open a new popup, nor blocks the window.top.location reset by the iFrame and simply continues refreshing the complete page to the '#targetURL'. It does the same with the default busting code.. so it's not because of some of my edits.

Anyone who is able to spot a mistake in my code?

Also, I would need a little modification that sees if the request has been made by an iframe or by the user itself, because now there is really NO option for a user to leave my page by changing the address in the toolbar or by clicking a link, which is not really needed LOL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've read the question yes, that's where I got the frame busting buster code from. Haven't really read any of the answers since this user want to find a solution to beat the frame busting buster.

Comment: did you read this
http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/anti-anti-frame-busting/

Comment: I only tested the latest version of IE

Comment: Actually even Google image didn't manage to do this with stackoverflow's frame busting for example: www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com&tbm=isch

Comment: So there might not be a foolproof solution afterall..

Comment: PENDO, a little more work on alternatives to the problem, I found a customizable jQuery lightbox plugin for working with custom windows yet (iframe, html, inline ajax etc). Maybe it will help. The following link: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: There is no foolproof method, since the browser can effectively treat any code as a *suggestion*. You're better off adhering to behavior standards (see: alertbox.com) and quit trying to force your users to do Weird Things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PENDO, I tried to simulate the whole process you described, ligthbox-jquery, javascript their own codes and controls opening pages via lightbox. I could not simulate at all, and as time is running out I'm sending a suggestion to broaden the range of possibilities and solutions.
I suggest replacing the redirect page:

```
 ...
  redirectUrl = $ ('# redirectUrl'). val ();
 ...
 window.top.location = 'http://www .****. with / ajax / nocontent.php';
 window.open (redirectUrl, "_blank");
```

Replaced with a DIV container that simulates a page, using ajax calls and taking the content and overwritten the contents of the DIV.

```
 ...
 $.post(redirectoURL /* or desired URL */, function(data) {
     $('DIV.simulateContent').html(data);
 });
 ...
```

or

```
 ...
 $('DIV.simulateContent').load(redirectoURL);
 ...
```

This approach also avoids the problem of preventing the user from even leaving your page using the address bar (as you yourself mentioned).

Sorry, let me give you a complete solution, but time prevented me.

PENDO, a little more work on alternatives to the problem, I found a customizable jQuery lightbox plugin for working with custom windows yet (iframe, html, inline ajax etc.). Maybe it will help. The following link:

```
 http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
```

Comment: thanks, i'll re-add a bounty because you obviously spend some time. It's not an option for us to load a page inside a div, since the user needs to get the experience from the page that is opened using the iframe. Loading it in a div just loads one page on my website, which would be fine.. but if a user clicks a link, they are most likely being redirected off my page anyway.

Comment: accepter your answer since you put in the most effort. We simply added target="_blank" to all outgoing links.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need javascript running in your iframe in IE, you can set the iframe security attribute :

```
<iframe security="restricted" src="http://domain.com" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: unfortunately, I guess that disabling javascript in an Twitter iFrame will cause major problems with the twitter page as it´s runnning completely on javascript=